# Converting to Date Month Format without the actual day

Tags: r, tibble

I have a dataframe that consist of the Month, Week of the Month and the Days of the Week (i.e Monday, Tuesday, etc)

I would like to convert them into Date Month format (e.g 02-Dec). How do I retrieve the date with just the week of the month and the days?

dput

```
structure(list(Month = c("Dec", "Jan", "Oct", "Jun", "Jan", "Oct", 
"Feb", "Nov", "Dec", "Apr", "Mar", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", 
"Aug", "Apr", "Jul", "May", "Apr"), WeekOfMonth = c(5, 3, 5, 
2, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4), DayOfWeek = c("Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Tuesday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
"Monday"), Year = c(1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: You would need the year as well, do you have that information?

Comment: @jpsmith i added the yeqar column

Comment: Maybe look into the package `lubridate`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
# get locale-specific days of week, and
# that first date is a Sunday
wdays <- weekdays(as.Date("2023-01-01") + 0:6)
dat |>
  transform(
    DayOfWeekNum = match(DayOfWeek, wdays), 
    date01 = as.Date(paste(Year, Month, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
  ) |>
  transform(weekday01 = as.integer(format(date01, format = "%w")) + 1L) |>
  transform(realdate = date01 + (WeekOfMonth - 1L) * 7L + (DayOfWeekNum - weekday01))
#    Month WeekOfMonth DayOfWeek Year DayOfWeekNum     date01 weekday01   realdate
# 1    Dec           5 Wednesday 1994            4 1994-12-01         5 1994-12-28
# 2    Jan           3 Wednesday 1994            4 1994-01-01         7 1994-01-12
# 3    Oct           5    Friday 1994            6 1994-10-01         7 1994-10-28
# 4    Jun           2  Saturday 1994            7 1994-06-01         4 1994-06-11
# 5    Jan           5    Monday 1994            2 1994-01-01         7 1994-01-24
# 6    Oct           4    Friday 1994            6 1994-10-01         7 1994-10-21
# 7    Feb           1  Saturday 1994            7 1994-02-01         3 1994-02-05
# 8    Nov           1    Friday 1994            6 1994-11-01         3 1994-11-04
# 9    Dec           4  Saturday 1994            7 1994-12-01         5 1994-12-24
# 10   Apr           3   Tuesday 1994            3 1994-04-01         6 1994-04-12
# 11   Mar           2    Sunday 1994            1 1994-03-01         3 1994-03-06
# 12   Mar           5    Monday 1994            2 1994-03-01         3 1994-03-28
# 13   Jan           3    Friday 1994            6 1994-01-01         7 1994-01-14
# 14   Jan           5    Friday 1994            6 1994-01-01         7 1994-01-28
# 15   Jan           5    Monday 1994            2 1994-01-01         7 1994-01-24
# 16   Aug           4   Tuesday 1994            3 1994-08-01         2 1994-08-23
# 17   Apr           4  Thursday 1994            5 1994-04-01         6 1994-04-21
# 18   Jul           5    Sunday 1994            1 1994-07-01         6 1994-07-24
# 19   May           4  Thursday 1994            5 1994-05-01         1 1994-05-26
# 20   Apr           4    Monday 1994            2 1994-04-01         6 1994-04-18
```

where `realdate` is (I believe) the date you're looking for.

(Since you have a `tibble`, I'm inferring `dplyr`, to which this can be translated trivially, a naive start would replace all `transform(.)` to `mutate(.)`, and then reduced to a single `mutate` call.)

---

### Verification

Using the calendar below (in linux, `cal 1994`), I'll randomly verify rows 5, 14, and 17 (chosen by `sort(sample(nrow(dat), size = 3))`).

- Row 5: `Jan, week 5, Monday, 1994`: the 5th week starts on Jan 23 (Sunday-based), that Monday is `1994-01-24`, check.
- Row 14: `Jan, week 5, Friday, 1994`: same start, Friday is `1994-01-28`, check.
- Row 17: `Apr, week 4, Thursday, 1994`: the fourth week starts on Apr 17, so Thursday is `1994-04-21`, check.

I'll leave it as an exercise to verify the remaining rows.

Disclaimer: while I didn't find anything here, there may be room for off-by-one (*seven, sire*) errors if the locale used to determine `WeekOfMonth` is different (i.e., not Sunday-based), in which case we might need to adjust ...

```
                            1994
      January               February               March
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1         1  2  3  4  5         1  2  3  4  5
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   6  7  8  9 10 11 12
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  13 14 15 16 17 18 19
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  20 21 22 23 24 25 26
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28                 27 28 29 30 31
30 31

       April                  May                   June
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2   1  2  3  4  5  6  7            1  2  3  4
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9   8  9 10 11 12 13 14   5  6  7  8  9 10 11
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  15 16 17 18 19 20 21  12 13 14 15 16 17 18
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  19 20 21 22 23 24 25
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  29 30 31              26 27 28 29 30


        July                 August              September
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2      1  2  3  4  5  6               1  2  3
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9   7  8  9 10 11 12 13   4  5  6  7  8  9 10
10 11 12 13 14 15 16  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  11 12 13 14 15 16 17
17 18 19 20 21 22 23  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24
24 25 26 27 28 29 30  28 29 30 31           25 26 27 28 29 30
31

      October               November              December
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1         1  2  3  4  5               1  2  3
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  11 12 13 14 15 16 17
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  18 19 20 21 22 23 24
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28 29 30           25 26 27 28 29 30 31
30 31
```

Comment: May I know how whats the variable wdays that you have suggested for MATCH?

Comment: Oops! Yes, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Some definitions:

- assuming year <strike>"2022"</strike> "1994"
- counting weeks within months by start of the week day (if first day in a month is Sunday it counts as the first week)
- choosing "Monday" as start of the week, so this might be off by a day.

A simple validity check would be line 9:

- December - Week 4 - Saturday: `24-Dec`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(start = ym(paste(Year, Month)), 
    end_date = start + (days_in_month(start) - 1), 
    weekdays = list(format(seq(start, end_date, by="day"), "%A")), 
    week_seg = list(cumsum(c(T, (weekdays == "Monday")[2:length(weekdays)]))), 
    first = grep(WeekOfMonth, week_seg)[1], 
    actual = {tmp <- grep(DayOfWeek, weekdays[week_seg == WeekOfMonth]); 
      ifelse(identical(tmp, integer(0)), 0, tmp)}, 
    date = format(ymd(paste(Year, Month, (first + actual) - 1)), "%d-%b")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(1:4, date)
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   Month WeekOfMonth DayOfWeek  Year date  
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1 Dec             5 Wednesday  1994 28-Dec
 2 Jan             3 Wednesday  1994 12-Jan
 3 Oct             5 Friday     1994 28-Oct
 4 Jun             2 Saturday   1994 11-Jun
 5 Jan             5 Monday     1994 24-Jan
 6 Oct             4 Friday     1994 21-Oct
 7 Feb             1 Saturday   1994 05-Feb
 8 Nov             1 Friday     1994 04-Nov
 9 Dec             4 Saturday   1994 24-Dec
10 Apr             3 Tuesday    1994 12-Apr
11 Mar             2 Sunday     1994 13-Mar
12 Mar             5 Monday     1994 28-Mar
13 Jan             3 Friday     1994 14-Jan
14 Jan             5 Friday     1994 28-Jan
15 Jan             5 Monday     1994 24-Jan
16 Aug             4 Tuesday    1994 23-Aug
17 Apr             4 Thursday   1994 21-Apr
18 Jul             5 Sunday     1994 31-Jul
19 May             4 Thursday   1994 19-May
20 Apr             4 Monday     1994 18-Apr
```

Comment: FYI the year is included in the OP data as 1994, not 2022 (I dont think it will change anything in your code)

Comment: @jpsmith Oh thanks, didn't see the edit. I'll check if it breaks anything :)

Comment: thanks @AndreWildberg, but I received an error:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `act = grep(DayOfWeek, weekdays[week_seg == WeekOfMonth])`.
✖ `act` must be size 1, not 0.
ℹ Did you mean: `act = list(grep(DayOfWeek, weekdays[week_seg == WeekOfMonth]))` ?
ℹ The error occurred in row 43.

At row 43: Jul
1
Monday
1994

Comment: @RshinyLearner Gonna have a look...

Comment: @RshinyLearner Made a change, should work now. Also removed the hardcoded `Year` to work with any date.